# Swift optional operator use

Tags: swift

```
//declaration

private var delegate: MyDelegate?
```

Should i be using this

```
delegate!.result(data)
```

or this

```
delegate?.result(data)
```

In the first version I believe the program will crash if delegate is not defined, but then in the second version, the program may not be calling the delegate back if it's not defined.

My question and concern is about crash and immediately letting me know that I did something wrong (which I wanna know) or a silent bug (that I forgot to pass delegate) that will take me some time to figure out, which is the better approach?

Comment: Check out this Apple Doc on Optional Chaining ["The main difference is that optional chaining fails gracefully when the optional is `nil`, whereas forced unwrapping triggers a runtime error when the optional is `nil`."](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/OptionalChaining.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It really depends on your design needs. Generally `delegate` is an optional, thus your `?` option is mostly used for this pattern.

That said, if you really want to enforce the presence of a delegate, you might constraint it to be defined in your designated initialiser.

Another option is the design you see in Xcode when declaring properties from Interface Builder: implicitly unwrap is used to let the init process terminate, then the decoder is supposed to decode and assign all the outlets.
Hence you see the `!`. In this case the outlets are intended to always be present, otherwise a crash is welcome.

In the end, I generally would use an optional for what is meant to be a delegate. But if I would want to enforce its presence I would enforce it during the initialisation process. This way you can't forget to pass a concrete delegate from the beginning ;-)

Comment: building on the question, can you please review if my approach here is correct or I should rewrite it for more elegance... I tried if let approach, but not happy with the result, want the cleanest approach if possible........
`if delegate != nil && delegate!.doeshaveRole() { //`

Comment: If you are adopting the delegate as an optional then `delegate?.doeshaveRole()` will return `Optional<T>` where `T` is the return type of `doeshaveRole()`. When you don't care if the delegate's method is actually called or about it's return value, you can just use the above syntax in one line of code. `if delegate?doeshaveRole() != nil { ...` can be used if you just need to check the case in which no delegate is present or its method returns `nil`. In case you need the actual non optional method's return value, the `if let hasRole = delegate?doeshaveRole() { ...` is preferred

Comment: actually I'm interested in the return value as well and I changed this to,......... `if let hasRole = delegate?.doesUserHaveRole() where hasRole == true {`, good? I wanted something clean, elegant and eloquent.

Comment: Yep, exactly how the `if let ... where ...` syntax is meant to be used.

Answer (score 3):

1) The fail doesn't have to be silent:

```
if let myData = delegate?.result(data) {
    // do something with myData
} else {
    // handle the fact that the delegate didn't work
}
```

2) I think that allowing a crash because of a forced unwrap with `!` is a bad idea: it defers the problem to the user at runtime if you miss it during your tests. Instead, the developer should take care of the problem at compile time; and with Optionals, Swift helps a lot to achieve this.

Answer (score 2):

Personally, I think the times when `!.` is a good idea are fairly rare.  Certainly, you would probably rather something fail silently in production unless it is totally critical.  It'd be a shame if a bug in your progress bar drawing crashed your app.  And if the operation is fundamental and critical to your application running properly, put some proper error handling around it!  And maybe tell your user something about what's wrong.

As a compromise, you could consider something like this:

```
func assertOnNil<T>(msg: String, defaultVal: T)->T {
    assertionFailure(msg)
    return defaultVal
}

func assertOnNil(msg: String)->() {
    assertionFailure(msg)
    return
}

// this will assert in debug builds
let x = "foo".toInt()?.successor() ?? assertOnNil("Should have been a number",0)
// this will print 0 in release builds
println(x)  


struct S {
    func f()->() { println("S.f") }
}

let s: S? = nil

// this will assert in debug builds but fail silently on release
s?.f() ?? assertOnNil("do-nothing chain")
```

This could be adapted to log error messages or throw up error dialogues instead.